# How can I see the code to my created Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Right now, to see the code of an existent stored procedure I have to RightClick -> Modify it, is there a way for me to just see the code?

Answer (score 4):

try running this:

```
exec sp_helptext 'YourProcedureName'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get it as a single string, use this:

```
SELECT definition 
FROM Sys.sql_modules 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('your procedure name here')
```

Marc